# Error with argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm having some issues with getting argparse to run correctly. Previously, my script would be run as follows:

`script.py <input_file(s)> <output_filename>`

With code that looked like this:

```
cell_list_input  = sys.argv[1:]
cell_list_output = sys.argv[len(cell_list_input)]
cell_list_input  = cell_list_input[:len(cell_list_input)-1]
```

However, I'd like to add some argument parsing just to make it more readable and usable. Ideally, the format would be similar with the following options:

`script.py -i <input_file(s)> -o <output_filename>`

`script.py --input_list <input_file(s)> --output <output_filename>`

The argparse equivalent I'm trying to implement looks like this right now:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_list', action='append', dest='input_list', default=[], help='Input list of cell names')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action='store', dest='output', help='Output file destination/name')
cli = parser.parse_args()
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure out what. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what's the error you're getting then?

Comment: So where's `-i`? And what do you mean *"something wrong"*?

Comment: Sorry, error coming from the `-i` option: `error: unrecognized arguments:` then all arguments passed into `-i`

Comment: you might want to consider using this approach (https://gist.github.com/martinth/ed991fb8cdcac3dfadf7) to multiple input files (either through pipes or through a list of filenames) followed by the `-o` argument.

Comment: @somada141 with the `'files'` option in the link you provided, can that be used with a `-i` argument?

Comment: no it just works as `cat file | python script.py` or `python script.py file1 file2 file3 --output output.txt`

Comment: @somada141 ah, okay. I think for the sake of this project, we'd like to differentiate all the command-line arguments and keep `-i` and `-o` in the command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `nargs` for your input file list. Try this:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_list', nargs="+", action='append', dest='input_list', default=[], help='Input list of cell names')
```

Complete example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_list', nargs="+", default=[], help='Input list of cell names')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output file destination/name')
cli = parser.parse_args()
print cli
```

Result:

```
$ python i.py -i a
Namespace(input_list=['a'], output=None)
$ python i.py -i a b c -o d
Namespace(input_list=['a', 'b', 'c'], output='d')
```

Comment: Hmm...now my cli.cell_list ends up being a list of a list...any way to get that resolved or does the nature of this always create a list of a list?